# Parabolic Regularity

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A have a following problem.

$u_t-\Delta u=f$ where $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega\times(0,T))$ and $\Omega\times(0,T)$ is a limited domain.

I want to know why $u\in C^{\infty}$. Actually result which ensures that $u\in C^{\infty}$?